# JavaScript. Интервал для собственных свойств

Tags: javascript, ооп, методы, setinterval

Не понимаю как использовать интервалы для обращения к свойствам объекта. Прошу у Вас помощи. В интернете ничего подобного не нашёл.

Вот например есть такой код:

```
example = new Example();
function Example() {
    this.TIME = 500;
    this.counter = 0;
    this.interval = null;
    this.step = function() {
        console.log(++this.counter);
    }
    this.start = function() {
        this.stop();
        this.interval = setInterval(this.step, this.TIME);
    }
    this.stop = function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
}
```

Функция *example.step();* работает верно. При вызове *example.start();* сообщается, что переменная counter - не число.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При вызове *setInterval/setTimeout* теряется контекст, переменная *this* ссылается на другой объект, у которого нет свойства *counter*.

Самый современный и простой способ сохранить контекст в колбэке - использовать bind(): `setInterval(this.step.bind(this), this.TIME);`. Но этот способ [не работает](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility) в IE8- и других старых браузерах.

Самый надёжный способ - сохранить ссылку на this в переменную и передавать в setInterval анонимную функцию:

```
var self = this;
this.interval = setInterval(function () {self.step()}, this.TIME);
```

Если вы используете возможности ES2015, то можно обойтись без дополнительной переменной:

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => this.step(), this.TIME);
```

[Интерактивный пример](https://jsfiddle.net/alexey_m_ukolov/cas2k1cu/1/)

Comment: самый современный и простой - объявить `step` как стрелочную функцию

Comment: последний вариант работать не будет, так как стрелочная функция не имеет this

Comment: @zhenyab, что значит "не имеет this"? Любая функция имеет this, стрелочная функция просто "наследует" this из того контекста, где была объявлена. Я добавил в ответ fiddle, можете убедиться.

Comment: @Grundy современный, да (хотя, пока что даже будущий всё же), но не самый простой, если ES2015 на проекте не используется. Это стоит использовать вместо третьего варианта с анонимной стрелочной функцией.

Comment: @АлексейУколов, это я к тому, что `bind` - уже довольно давно доступен, поэтому назвать его _самым современным_ не совсем верно